# tornado app failing to set cookie after FB login with OAuth

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, cookies, tornado

I have written a tornado app which uses FB authentication. First it gets permission from the user & gets an access token. And then it makes another call to the FB with the access token, get the email id and save it in a cookie.

Following is the handler:

```
class FAuthLoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        user_id = self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')

        if self.get_argument('code', None):
            self.get_authenticated_user(
                redirect_uri=settings.redirect_url,
                client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'],
                client_secret=self.settings['facebook_secret'],
                code=self.get_argument('code'),
                callback=self.async_callback(self._on_facebook_login))
            return
        elif self.get_secure_cookie('access_token'):
            self.redirect('/')
            return

        self.authorize_redirect(
            redirect_uri=settings.redirect_url,
            client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'],
            extra_params={'scope': 'email'}
        )


    def _on_facebook_login(self, user):                
        if not user:
            self.clear_all_cookies()
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, 'Facebook authentication failed')

        # print "http//graph.facebook.com/%s/picture" % str(user['id'])
        # print "http//graph.facebook.com/%s" % str(user['id'])

        self.set_secure_cookie('fb_id', str(user['id']))
        self.set_secure_cookie('access_token', str(user['access_token']))
        self.facebook_request("/me", access_token=user["access_token"], callback=self.async_callback(self._save_user_profile))
        self.redirect('/')

    def _save_user_profile(self, user):
        if not user:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Facebook authentication failed.")
        # print user
        print user.get('email')
        self.set_secure_cookie('trakr', user.get('email'))
        print self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')
```

Inside `_save_user_profile`, the first `print` statement prints the email id the user logged in. It successfully prints my email. Then I try to save that in the cookie, but when I print that I am getting response as `None`

I thought I messed with using classes & may be I was using wrong `self`. I printed `id` of `self` in several places, seems it's same. And I also printed `dir(self)` and it does have `set_secure_cookie` function. So why it is failing to set the cookie?

Answer (score 1):

You're redirecting the user away before you have a chance to set the cookie.  Remove the redirect call in `_on_facebook_login` and move it to the end of `_save_user_profile`.

Also, you can't read a cookie back immediately after you set it - setting cookies will take effect on the *next* request; the get_cookie APIs return the cookies that were present when the request came in.

Comment: but I am calling it before redirecting right? and also, inside _save_user_profile, it is printing the email, that means control was here right? so why it is not able to save the cookies?

Comment: No, you're not calling `_save_user_profile` before redirecting.  You're making a request to have `_save_user_profile` called at some point in the future, but that call hasn't happened before you call `self.redirect`.  Just because control reaches `_save_user_profile`, it doesn't mean that the browser is still paying attention to receive the new cookies.

Comment: 'Just because control reaches _save_user_profile, it doesn't mean that the browser is still paying attention to receive the new cookies.' Why is that? Whats the reason behind this?